# Hiding a tab on SharePoint

Tags: top-link-bar

Is there an easy way to hide a tab in sharepoint? I've tried going to: site actions -> site settings -> top link bar but it doesn't give an option to hide the tab. It only gives you the option of editing the link and deleting the tab all together. I want to be able to hide the tab from everyone, but be able to access it/put it back up if needed. I've seen responses to similar questions, but they say to change user's permissions, which I don't think is the right way to do it for me. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you want to hide it from specific pages? or entire site?

Comment: You can use either jQuery/JavaScript or CSS to hide a specific tab. I don't know if it applies in your specific situation. Here is a JavaScript that hides tabs: https://sharepoint247.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/javascript-to-hide-or-select-specific-tabs-in-sharepoint-ribbon/ Have a look to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: @users1100 I'd like to hide it from the entire home page. It's a tab (in the top link bar) that isn't important right now. If you click the tab, it brings you to another page. It's not the sharepoint ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on a site for which the publishing features are enabled, you have the option of showing or hiding pages and subsites on the top link bar.

1. On the Site actions menu  Site Actions Menu, click Site settings.
2. In the Look and Feel section, click Navigation.

   NOTE   The Navigation command appears under Look and Feel only if the publishing features are enabled for your site and you have the at lease the permissions obtained by being added to the default Designers SharePoint group for the site.
3. In the Navigation Editing and Sorting section, do one of the
   following:

   - If you want to show a subsite or page that is hidden, select the item, and then click Show.
   - If you want to hide a subsite or page that is currently visible on
     the top link bar, select the item, and then click Hide.

Move Global Navigation[image]

NOTES

- The Hide and Show commands are available only for navigation items
  that are subsites or pages. You cannot hide headings or links.
- When you select an item that is currently visible in the Quick
  Launch, only the Hide option is available. When you select an item
  that is currently hidden in the Quick Launch, only the Show option is
  displayed.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-top-link-bar-for-site-navigation-1B614211-2882-4507-A791-8716090C9905#__toc278883945

If publishing isn’t a part of your site hierarchy, then you can do the following with your team site navigation through Site Settings:

- Add new links
- Control the order of the links
- Nest the links under a heading style structure (Quick Launch only)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SP 2013 --> Go to Site settings --> Navigation. Use the below setting:
[image]

Now by default in all pages, the top ribbon tabs are hidden. If you want to see the tabs in any page. Click on Gear icon next to user name--> Click on Show ribbon.

[image]

Comment: I'm unfortunately using sharepoint 2010, and it doesn't give me the navigation option.